# How can I debug a running Kiosk-mode Chrome application?

Tags: google-chrome-app

I have a Chrome application that experiences issues only when being run in kiosk mode. Is there any way to connect a debugger or enable the inspector for Kiosk-mode applications?

Comment: I have the same problem but more specific, the problem occurs when running the app in Kiosk mode on a specific ChromeBox. Is there a way to connect a debugger, write remote log statements or visualise logging info on the device itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug a Kiosk Chrome application running on a Chromebox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444971/how-to-debug-a-kiosk-chrome-application-running-on-a-chromebox)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you run Chrome with the `--remote-debugging-port=9222` option it will provide access to DevTools at `http://localhost:9222/`. If you need to access it from a different computer you can forward the port with ssh.

Source: http://blog.chromium.org/2011/05/remote-debugging-with-chrome-developer.html

Comment: Thanks, this is useful, but I can't see how to apply it to the case of kiosk mode on a ChromeOS device (i.e. a true kiosk).

Comment: I provided a more detailed answer to Bob Groeneveld's question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444971/how-to-debug-a-kiosk-chrome-application-running-on-a-chromebox/27454778