# chrome devtools, how to open when in kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I've got a chrome kiosk application that talks to a local C# webapp. This is on windows.

Were in the final stages of development and once we turn on and run chrome in kiosk mode, we can't get to the devtools to say, look at an an error in the console.

Is there a way to open the devtools via javascript?  I've looked doesn't seem possible.

Any other techniques/approaches possible to collect the log on request?

Comment: Why not capture all errors and send them back to the server?

Comment: that's likely where I'm headed.

Answer (score -1):

> If you run Chrome with the --remote-debugging-port=9222 option it will provide access to DevTools at http://localhost:9222/.

Source: [How to debug a Kiosk Chrome application running on a Chromebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27444971/how-to-debug-a-kiosk-chrome-application-running-on-a-chromebox)